# Retrieving information with the ProfilesApp Library in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been working with the Profiles Library to retrieve and update some shared contacts in apps script. I'm not expert at all and I'm having some trouble with the following scenario:

I always want to retrieve some specific "fields" for each element, such as Name, Company, Department, Position, Email, work phone, mobile phone. The problem is that I don't know how to o it dynamically, so when I retrieve a field that has no value I het an unpleasant "undefined" that I don't want to be printed on the spreadsheet, I've tried try/catch, an if statement to guarantee that the value exists before printing it, but without any luck.

The retreiving function is the following:

```
function listAllProfiles() {
 var profiles = null;
 var token = null;
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 do {
   var result = ProfilesApp.getProfilesForPaging(token);
   profiles = result.getProfiles();
   token = result.getToken();
   for (var i = 0; i < profiles.length; i++) {
     var workEmail, workPhone, mobilePhone, noEmpleado;
     var emails = profiles[i].getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_EMAIL);
     var workPhones = profiles[i].getPhones(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_PHONE);
     var mobilePhones = profiles[i].getPhones(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE);
     var custom = profiles[i].getCustomFields(ContactsApp.Field.NUMERO_DE_EMPLEADO);    

     for (var j in emails) { workEmail = emails[0].getAddress(); } 
     for (var k in workPhones) { workPhone = workPhones[k].getPhoneNumber(); }
     for (var l in mobilePhones) 
     { if ( mobilePhones[l].getPhoneNumber() != undefined) { //this is not working
       mobilePhone = mobilePhones[l].getPhoneNumber(); } else {
      Logger.log("does not exist");
    }
  }
  for (var m in custom) { noEmpleado = custom[m].getValue(); }


// Sólo imprime usuarios reales dados de alta
      if (workEmail != ".@nchezg.com") { 
        if(workEmail != "secure-data-connector-user@nchezg.com"){ 
             sheet.appendRow([profiles[i].getFullName(),profiles[i].getCompanyName(),profiles[i].getDepartment(),profiles[i].getJobTitle(),workEmail,
                           profiles[i].getOfficeLocation(),workPhone,mobilePhone,noEmpleado]);
        }
      }
    }
  } while (token != null);
}
```

I think that by retrieving this information dynamically will end with the undefined problem but I don't know how to do it, so any help or recommendation on how to do it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do any of the posts answer your question? If so please use the "tick" option to mark that response as the answer. If not, you should edit your question and clarify it so people have an opportunity to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you want to handle the case where there's no data held. Here's a one liner example for a work phone number that you can apply to any similar scenarios. It works like this: if `getPhones(...)` returns one or more PhoneFields then assign the first phone number to the variable `workPhoneNumber` otherwise assign an empty string.

```
//gets first work phone number from a ProfilesApp Profile
var workPhoneNumber = profile.getPhones(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_PHONE).length >
  0 ? profile.getPhones(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_PHONE)[0].getPhoneNumber() :  '';
```